# warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, embedded-linux, memcpy

I am working on a c code which is to be run on embedded linux. I have to copy the contents of an array to a block of memory. I have defined the base address of the memory as:

```
#define BASE_ADDRESS 0x40000000
```

Now when I memcpy the contents of an array onto the base address, I get the warning of making a pointer from integer without a cast. How do I remove this warning? This is my code:

```
unsigned int rx1_arr[64] = {0}; //some data is added to this array before memcpy
memcpy(BASE_ADDRESS, &rx1_arr, 64*sizeof(int));
```

Comment: `BASE_ADDRESS` is of integer type, `memcpy` expects its first argument is of type `void *`.

Comment: Yes I worked that out.

Comment: memcpy((void *)BASE_ADDRESS, &rx1_arr, 64*sizeof(int)); also worked

Comment: `memcpy((void *)BASE_ADDRESS, &rx1_arr, 64*sizeof(unsigned int));`

Comment: I have a single base address and almost 200 offset addresses. Adding (void*) directly to the memcpy function was an easier task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to cast to the void poiner

```
 memcpy((void *)BASE_ADDRESS, rx1_arr, 64*sizeof(int));
```

there is no need of the address operator `&` in front of the rx1_arr.

`rx1_arr`, `&rx1_arr`, `&rx1_arr[0]` point to the same address but have different types.

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [Documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm), `memcpy` expects the first parameter to be a `void *` but your are giving `BASE_ADDRESS` which is an `int`. The error given is :

> note: expected 'void * restrict' but argument is of type 'int'

Just cast it to a `void *`

```
memcpy((void *)BASE_ADDRESS, &rx1_arr, 64*sizeof(int));
```

Ps : don't use `&rx1_arr` in your `memcpy` but use `rx1_arr`